# Is there a python equivalent to Ada protected object?

Tags: python, ada

I'm using python for my latest project and I am wondering if there is a python equivalent for the Ada protected object, so I can access data safely across processes.

Answer (score 1):

Python standard library has a package called [multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html) which has many things to help you writing multiprocessing applications, you should take a look there, specially from  [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#exchanging-objects-between-processes)

You have queues and pipes to send messages between processes, Value and Array classes to share objects safely between processes and also equivalents from threading like locks.

Also take a look at Manager() to create safe List, Dict and others.

Comment: The python multiprocessing features you mention don't have any direct comparison with Ada's protected types.
There are no automatically evaluated guards, or requeue for example.